# Writing a custom comparer for a core class in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, comparator, sortedset

I need to write a comparer for a core class in C#. I have a `SortedSet<Vector2>` and in order to iterate through it I need a basic comparer. Nothing fancy needed as I just need to access each element in the collection in any order. But Vector2 (`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics`) is a compiled dll without a default comparer.

My `SortedSet` has a property [`Comparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) but I cannot figure how to assign Comparer a Vector2 comparer.

Comment: Pass it to the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your own class which implements `IComparer<Vector2>` and then constructor your `SortedSet` with it:

```
SortedSet<Vector2> sorted = new SortedSet<Vector2>(new MyCustomComparer());
```

Your comparer just needs to implement the single method [`Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3.aspx):

```
public class MyCustomComparer : IComparer<Vector2>
{
    public int Compare(Vector2 x, Vector2 y)
    {
        // Return appropriate value here, depending on the sort order you want
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also possible to derive from `Comparer<T>` instead of `IComparer<T>` directly. I slightly prefer `Comparer<T>` since you also get `IComparer` for free, but doesn't really matter in practice.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I just deleted an almost identical comment of mine (yours was first).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create your custom comparer by implementing the `IComparer<T>` interface for `Vector2`.

You then have to instantiate your custom comparer and pass it to the constructor of SortedSet:

[SortedSet(T) Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395024.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Skeet has given one good solution. If you use .NET version 4.5, you can also use a lambda expression, like this:

```
new SortedSet<Vector2>(Comparer<Vector2>.Create(
    (v1, v2) => v1.X.CompareTo(v2.X)
    )
```

In the above example I just supposed the `Vector2` values should simply be compared by `X` coordinate (and vectors with same `X` will be considered equally "great" by my comparer).

For another example comparing by length:

```
new SortedSet<Vector2>(Comparer<Vector2>.Create(
    (v1, v2) => (v1.X * v1.X + v1.Y * v1.Y).CompareTo(v2.X * v2.X + v2.Y * v2.Y)
    )
```

Of course, if the logic determining if `v1` is less, equal, or greater than `v2` is complex, it's better to have a usual method for it, but for simple things, lambdas are great because you don't need to write a new `class` or anything.

Comment: Even better if you write the comparer as a separate object and then only use it as a parameter in the SortedSet constructor.